# Impala UDF in Python, using later version of Impyla and numba

Tags: python, impala

I am using impyla==0.13.5 (or 0.13.7), numba==0.23.1. Is it possible to get impala udf working in python for these version? I looked into some cloudera tutorial, but it seems the impala udf is deprecated in later versions of python packages. And I got error when I tried to do:

```
from impala.udf import udf, ship_udf

ImportError: No module named udf
```

Has anyone ever successfully get impala udf working in python in the later version of impyla? Or anything similar? Thanks!